# datetime comparison with string?

Tags: python, datetime

Given a *string* in the `datetime` format of `strftime('%b %d, %Y %I:%M %p')`
eg: `'Apr 17, 2016 02:00 AM'`

is there a way to check if this time has already past?
like may be compare

```
datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%b %d, %Y %I:%M %p')
```

somehow to the string `'Apr 17, 2016 02:00 AM'`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Parse the string into a `datetime.datetime` instance then compare to `datetime.now()`:

```
from datetime import datetime

dt = datetime.strptime('Apr 17, 2016 02:00 AM', '%b %d, %Y %I:%M %p')
if dt < datetime.now():
    print('{} alread past'.format(dt))
```

You might like to make that a function:

```
def is_past(dt_string):
    return datetime.strptime(dt_string, '%b %d, %Y %I:%M %p') < datetime.now()
```

And then call it like this:

```
>>> is_past('Apr 17, 2016 02:00 AM')
False
>>> is_past('Apr 01, 2016 02:00 AM')
True
```

Answer (score 6):

No, string comparison would not work here; the values do not sort according to the full date, but according to the month and day of the month, with the first 10 days of the month eratically dispersed throughout that sort as the day number is not zero-padded. If the year was listed first, followed by a zero-padded numeric month, day, hours (using a 24 hour clock) and minutes, *then* you could do it as strings only, because then the lexicographical sort happens to match the way the date and time would be sorted.

Instead, parse your string to a `datetime` object using the [`datetime.datetime.strptime()` class method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime):

```
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(string, '%b %d, %Y %I:%M %p')
if dt < datetime.datetime.now():
    # in the past.
```

Demo:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> string = 'Apr 17, 2016 02:00 AM'
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(string, '%b %d, %Y %I:%M %p')
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 17, 2, 0)
>>> dt < datetime.datetime.now()
False
```

If you were to format your dates using the [ISO8601 combined date-time format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations), then you'd have a format that can be sorted as strings only:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
'2016-04-15T09:55:09.907130'
```